# Как установить атрибут src тега img через css?

Tags: html, css

Как установить атрибут src тега img через css?

Answer (score 6):

никак :)

Однако есть альтернативные варианты: background любому элементу либо свойство content в css.

Answer (score 6):

Через css никак. Разве что можете попробовать для `img` задавать в css `background-image`.

Answer (score 5):

Да ладно никак :)

хоть и грязный трюк - [но работает](http://jsfiddle.net/JHL9u/2/)

Comment: не только грязно но также и некроссбраузерно

Comment: вопрос же не как кроссбраузерно это сделать.

Comment: Ну про крозбраузерность никто не говорил :) Я просто указал на возможный вариант

Answer (score 2):

Через Css нельзя установить src img а можно:

1. С помощью div'ов: `<div style="width:40px;height:40px;background-image: url('адрес');"></div>`
2. На JS используя id: `<script>document.getElementById("ид картинки").src="адрес";</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, у меня вот так, работает в браузерах (Yandex, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Maxthon - это те, что проверил)

```css
    div a.link:after {
    content:url(http://savepic.ru/11603915.png) !important;
    }
    img.logo{
    display:none !important;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="link">
    <img class="logo" src="/images/img.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

Ещё один способ (нубам, возвещающим, что через css никак - не смотреть, а то разрыв шаблона :) )
https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Comment: img нужен для тех случаев, когда размер картинки зависит от ширины экрана, в этом случае его не заменить на background и не заменить на content к сожалению, так как для content url нельзя задавать размеры.